# rails 4 jquery plugin fileupload loads twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using jquery fileupload plugin about the same way as presented in Railscasts 381.

Since I'm using Rails4, the Turbolinks caused me a lot of trouble.

Sometimes the plug-in loads twice. Sometimes, it doesn't load at all.

I tried a lot of options but I couldn't get it to work correctly.

Right now, I have this set-up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#new_picture").fileupload({
            dataType: "script",
            add: function(e, data) {
                $("#picture_submit_button").addClass("disabled");
                console.log("data context:" + data.context);
                data.formData = $("#new_picture").serializeArray();
                var file;
                file = data.files[0];
                data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file));
                $("#new_picture").append(data.context);
                data.submit();
                return $("#page-loading").hide();
            },
            progress: function(e, data) {
                var progress;
                if (data.context) {
                    progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    return data.context.find(".bar").css("width", progress + "%");
                }
            },
            stop: function(e, data) {
                $("#picture_submit_button").removeClass("disabled");
                $(".upload").remove();

            }
        });
```

});

When I reload the page, it's ok. When I then go to another page, it's gone.

I tried to reload the plug-in after every page change with a variable isLoaded like that:

```
var isLoaded=false;

function documentReadyOperations() {

if(!isLoaded) {
   $("#new_picture").fileupload({ ... });
   isLoaded = true;
}
}

$(document).bind('page:change', function() {
    documentReadyOperations();

});
```

but this doesn't work either.

What's the right way to manage these plugins?

Comment: You could always disable turbo links

Comment: Yes but I like it! ;-)

Comment: I've had similar issues with jQuery and Turbolinks and found that the [`jquery-turbolinks`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem helps resolve issues with `bind` events.

Comment: I tried it but with no luck. It keeps loading the plug-in twice. I can't believe there is no easy way to detect if the plug-in is loaded. Unbelievable!

Comment: Have you checked the console and/or the source of the page to see if the script is loaded twice or maybe your `fileupload` gets initialized in multiple places?

Comment: Yes sure. It is loaded twice.